# Comparing 2 GridViews in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How can I compare the infos in the 2 [GridViews](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx), and when I click the button compare, the information that is not the same will appear in another datagridview?

For example the info. in the first datagridview is 12345
second datagridview is 1234567
then, when I click the compare button,
67 will appear in another datagridview.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the markup for your 2 GridViews?  And what code you've tried so far to compare them?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

1. In the code behind assign the datasource to gridviews

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (!Page.IsPostBack)
       {
           List lists1 = new List();

   ```
       lists1.Add(1);
       lists1.Add(12345);
       lists1.Add(234354);
       lists1.Add(3421);
       lists1.Add(2343);

       g1.DataSource = lists1;
       g1.DataBind();

       List<int> lists2 = new List<int>();

       lists2.Add(1);
       lists2.Add(1234567);
       lists2.Add(234354);
       lists2.Add(334421);
       lists2.Add(2343343);

       g2.DataSource = lists2;
       g2.DataBind();
   }
   ```

   }
2. On the compare button click do the comparison.

   protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       List newLists = new List();

   ```
   //iterate first gridview
   foreach (GridViewRow row1 in g1.Rows)
   {
       if (row1.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           string gv1Value = row1.Cells[0].Text;

           //iterate second gridview
           foreach (GridViewRow row2 in g2.Rows)
           {
               if (row2.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
               {
                   string gv2Value = row2.Cells[0].Text;

                   //do comparison here
                   if (gv1Value.Contains(gv2Value))
                   {
                       //if your criteria are met, put the data in the new lists
                       newLists.Add(Convert.ToInt32(gv1Value));
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }

   if (newLists.Count > 0)
   {
       g3.DataSource = newLists;
       g3.DataBind();
   }
   ```

   }

Hope this helps

Comment: the result of this code is not i wanted its vice versa. the result that i want is to find their difference not the same number in two tables. And thank you for this code :)

Comment: What if the data that I will be putting in the gridview 1&2 is from sqldatasource? What codes will I change? thank u so much